# how to use jquery key value array?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, key-value

I need help adding a key value array for this jQuery code I came across. The code does exactly what I need, except I need multiple inputs unlike the single input it provides.

```
jQuery("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var caretPos = document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = jQuery("#txt").val();
    var txtToAdd = "stuff";
    jQuery("#txt").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70">There is some text here.</textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" />
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NaHTw/4/).

I want to have an array such as:

```
OK => stuff,
YES => more stuff,
NO => no stuff
```

I'm not that familiar with jQuery, please help.

Comment: is it intends three buttons with different value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have an arrays with string keys, only indexed arrays. But you can use an object for that purpose. 
Change your code as shown below:

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70">There is some text here.</textarea>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="OK" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="NO" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="YES" />
```

---

```
$(".btn").on('click', function() {
    var caretPos = document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $("#txt").val();
    var txtSet = {'ok' : 'stuff', 'yes' : 'more stuff', 'no' : 'no stuff'};
    var txtToAdd = txtSet[$(this).val().toLowerCase()];
    $("#txt").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
});
```

Now you can easily extend the object `txtSet` due to the variety of possible buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pg5zmqg/